# Netsuite webservices get order/invoice request, items type is blank

Tags: web-services, netsuite

Does anyone know how to get the type of an item that is on an order or invoice via a getRequest?

When I get the list of items via the getRequest (webservices) from the order or invoice, the type fields in the items are empty.

So I can't then do a new getRequest to get the item because I don't know the item type.
This then makes to many requests as I will need to do a search for the item ID first to find the item type to get the actual item.

**EDITED**

This is my getRequest:

```
$service = new APDIBLE\NetSuite\NetSuiteService($netsuite_config);
$request = new APDIBLE\NetSuite\Classes\GetRequest();
$request->baseRef = new APDIBLE\NetSuite\Classes\RecordRef();
$request->baseRef->internalId = $internalid;
$request->baseRef->type = 'salesOrder';
$getResponse = $service->get($request);
```

And that works fine, i get the salesOrder without error. It is just all the RecordRef fields including the items in the itemlist have an empty type field. I have noticed this is with every getRequest that i do for anything, they type field is always empty.

this is my XML Request if it helps:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:ns2="urn:messages_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns3="ns">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns3:applicationInfo xsi:type="ns2:ApplicationInfo">
        <ns2:applicationId>************************************</ns2:applicationId>
    </ns3:applicationInfo>
    <ns3:passport xsi:type="ns1:Passport">
        <ns1:email>**********</ns1:email>
        <ns1:password>***********</ns1:password>
        <ns1:account>***********</ns1:account>
        <ns1:role internalId="**********"/>
    </ns3:passport>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:get>
        <ns2:baseRef xsi:type="ns1:RecordRef" type="salesOrder" internalId="4153"/>
    </ns2:get>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

and this is the returned item value of one of the list items:

```
 <tranSales:item internalId="2451" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2015_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                            <platformCore:name>test non-inventory item</platformCore:name>
                        </tranSales:item>
```

You can see the item ID and name is there but no type is returned. and this is the same for all RecordRef fields.

Comment: can you pls show us your code?

Comment: i have added the geRequest above. I have also noted how i have found out that all my RecordRef type fields are empty for every single getRequest i make for everything. Which is silly if i need to know what the item type is, if it could be a number of different types.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard NetSuite behavior.

In nearly all cases where items are referenced the type is not defined alongside the record reference. There's not a way to change this behavior in the API. Searching for the item type is one way to pull the type so you can `get` the item from the NetSuite API.

You could also just attempt to `get` the item with a list of the most popular item types. This is often faster since a NetSuite `get` call to an invalid record reference is very quick to execute, often orders-of-magnitude faster than a search.

Here's an example implementation:

https://github.com/NetSweet/netsuite/blob/659d4634e8ab2ae26d8a860ecb5fc47a803da7c7/lib/netsuite/utilities.rb#L164